# How can I add a env variable to a kubernetes deployment using golang?

Tags: go, kubernetes

I need to set or add a environment variable to a existing kubernetes deployment using golang. It should be added to the config after a restart.

```
func (r *SparkETLReconciler) DoRestart(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    r.Log.Info("restart hit!")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", req.URL.Path[1:])
    found := &appsv1.Deployment{}
    err := r.Get(ctx, types.NamespacedName{
        Name:      "vmc-etl-test",
        Namespace: "ndl",
    }, found)

    if err != nil {
        r.Log.Error(err, "deploy check failed")
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "I found the deployment!")
    }

    deleteErr := r.DeleteAllOf(ctx, &corev1.Pod{}, client.InNamespace("ndl"), client.MatchingLabels{"operatorETLName": req.URL.Path[1:])

    if deleteErr != nil {
        r.Log.Error(deleteErr, "deletion of deployment's pods failed")
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Deployment's pods deleted, restarting")
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some information about what was tried before. And what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you fetched the your deployment, you can add env variable in the following manner.

```golang
# Assuming you have only 1 container in the Pod
found.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[0].Env = []v1.EnvVar{
        {
            Name:  "ENV_VARIABLE_NAME",
            Value: "ENV_VARIABLE_VALUE",
        },
}
```

Needless to say, if you already have some env variables in your container, then you'd better `append()` them, otherwise you'll override them.

Also, you'll need to send a call to `Update()` (or `CreateOrUpdate()`) your deployment.